# docker apache container serves /usr/local/apache2/htdocs as DocumentRoot instead of /var/www/html

Tags: php, docker, apache

I have a docker-compose and apache.dockerfile which I am using to create a local server. It's a pretty basic setup.

I set up a virtual host in `httpd-vhosts.conf` and I know the server name and alias name is working because if i go to `dev.flying` I see the "It works!"  page (which is the default index.html in htdocs).

However why wouldn't the document root declaration also be working?

docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  apache:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: apache.dockerfile
    container_name: dev_apache
    depends_on:
      - php
      - mysql
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./wordpress:/var/www/html:delegated
```

apache.dockerfile

```
FROM httpd:alpine

ADD ./apache/httpd-vhosts.conf /usr/local/apache2/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin email@email.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ServerName dev.flying
    ServerAlias dev.flying
    ErrorLog logs/dev.flying-error_log
    CustomLog logs/dev.flying-access_log commo

    <Location /var/www/html>
            ProxyPass http://localhost:9000/
            ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:9000/
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into some documentations here is what I think you will need to do (maybe with some changes to fit in your configuration)

[The httpd docker official image docs](https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd#Configuration) recommends to export the configuration first

```bash
$ docker run --rm httpd:2.4 cat /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf > ./apache/my-httpd.conf # Dumping to your apache folder
```

then after editing as you want copy the edited part for your container. In this case you will need to tell apache to include vhosts configuration uncommenting the line

```
# Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

After that you virtual host configuration will override any request made for the server even if not matching the `ServerName` (you'll not see the htdocs default anymore)

**docker-compose.yml** - Example

```yaml
services:
  apache:
    image: httpd:alpine # Using the image directly since everything is accessible through the volumes
    container_name: dev_apache
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./wordpress:/var/www/html:delegated
      - ./apache/my-httpd.conf:/usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
      - ./apache/httpd-vhosts.conf:/usr/local/apache2/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

### Edit

Also you will want a [Directory directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#directory) to give permission in `/var/www/html` directory since the default directive in `my-httpd.conf` is to deny the entire server filesystem. Something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <...> Your stuff <...>
    <Directory /var/www/html>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks will give this a go this weekend.